# How to inject a javascript script in a webview before the html load in android 7

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I'll present a modified example of my problem to simplify this question, but the essence is the same for my full example:

I need to load a html code inside a webview, this code, assumes some javascript functions to be declared. Example HTML code:

```
<html>
<body><h1>JavaScript Math.random()</h1>
<p>A random number:</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>showRandomValue();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

in this example, the code assumes a declared function called `showRandomValue()`. So I need to inject this function before the code is executed. This is the FUNCTION I want to inject:

```
<script>
function showRandomValue() {
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.random();
      }
</script>
```

Until now I was doing this in the before loading the code in the webview:

```
public static final String JAVASCRIPT_FUNCTION = 
        "javascript:function showRandomValue() {\n" +
        "           document.getElementById(\"demo\").innerHTML = Math.random();\n" +
        "      }";
webView.loadUrl(JAVASCRIPT_FUNCTION);
webView.loadData(HTML_CODE, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

This worked well for me, until I wanted to update my targetSdkVersion to 24. If I set `targetSdkVersion 24` this code stops working because when the code gets loaded the function is not found.

Revising the android WebView documentation I found this:

> Compatibility note. Applications targeting N or later, JavaScript state from an empty WebView is no longer persisted across navigations like loadUrl(String). For example, global variables and functions defined before calling loadUrl(String) will not exist in the loaded page. Applications should use addJavascriptInterface(Object, String) instead to persist JavaScript objects across navigations.

My problem is that with `addJavascriptInterface` you can declare a custom object, so I could declare:

```
webview.addJavascriptInterface(new MyInterface(),"javaInterface");
```

and call its method with, in example, `javaInterface.getRandomValue()`. But I can't declare global functions with this method.

**Important**: I can't edit or modify the HTML code since it comes from a third party server.

How can I make this code to work again in android 7+?

This is the full example code if you want to test it:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    String HTML_CODE = "<html>\n" +
            "<body><h1>Hello World</h1>\n" +
            "<p>A random number:</p>\n" +
            "<p id=\"demo\"></p>\n" +
            "<script>showRandomValue();</script>\n" +
            "</body>\n" +
            "</html>";

    public static final String JAVASCRIPT_FUNCTION = "(function showRandomValue() {document.getElementById(\"demo\").innerHTML = Math.random();})";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:" + JAVASCRIPT_FUNCTION);
        webView.loadData(HTML_CODE, "text/html", "UTF-8");
    }    
}
```

Compiling this code with targetSdkVersion 23 will work and with targetSdkVersion 24 will fail to show the random number

Comment: What is your minSdk?

Comment: It seems that `JavaScriptInterface` will work for you perfectly well if you make changes in both the app code as well as the server code. And if it is not possible to make changes on server code, Then I think you don't have any solution available now. You can try reporting this issue to Google.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you said that you cannot modify HTML... but if you do loadData with prefetched content I don't see any reason against injecting your desired function into html head in script tag. All in all thing which you do is already a bit hacky.